Issue with Bucket Sort Implementation in Python
I'm trying to implement the bucket sort algorithm using Python. My current implementation seems to have a problem when dealing with integer values outside the range of 0 to 1. Specifically, the index calculation for bucket placement results in an index that is out of the range of the number of buckets.
this is my code:
def bucketsort(array):
    bucket = []

    for i in range (len(array)):
        bucket.append([])

    for j in array:
        index_b = int(10*j)
        bucket[index_b].append(j)

    for i in range(len(array)):
        bucket[i] = sorted(bucket[i])

    k = 0
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(len(bucket[i])):
            array[k] = bucket[i][j]
            k += 1
    return array

array = [12, 84, 64, 65, 94, 46, 99]
print("Sorted array is: ", bucketsort(array))

When I run this code with the array [12, 84, 64, 65, 94, 46, 99], show an IndexError due to the calculated bucket index being out of range.
How can I modify my implementation to handle a general case of integer arrays?

What was your reasoning to do index_b = int(10*j) ? Where does that magic number 10 come from, and why multiply with it?

i see then i should multiply the range of the buckets with j
thank you

It would help if you included your desired results; [mre] and [ask]

Here is the general implementation, hope it helps:
def bucketsort(arr):
    min_val, max_val = min(arr), max(arr)
    total_buckets = len(arr)
    buckets = [[] for _ in range(total_buckets)]

    for val in arr:
        bucket_number = int(total_buckets * (val - min_val) / (max_val - min_val + 1))
        buckets[bucket_number].append(val)

    return [val for bucket in buckets for val in sorted(bucket)]


Your implementation looks very nice. But the question wasn't about an implementation, but rather to help find the issues in his implementation. Also, your answer lacks an explanation of how it works; just code helps nobody. If you add that, it would be a good answer.

Ah I see, thanks for your feedback. Appreciate it, will be incorporating it in my other answers.

The expression index_b = int(10*j) does not make much sense. The coefficient 10 is strange (why 10?) and it just maps every value of the input list to a number that is 10 times as large. Interpreting that as an index is not giving you anything useful, and will often be an index that is out of bounds.
Instead, you'd typically choose a number of buckets that is fixed (like maybe 10 buckets), and then you'd determine for each bucket which should be the distinct range of values that belong in it.
Here is one way to do it:
def bucketsort(array): 
    num_buckets = 10  # Make 10 buckets

    buckets = [[] for i in range(num_buckets)]

    # Determine what the spread is of the values in the input
    low = min(array)
    high = max(array)
    #  ... and what would be the range-size per bucket
    span = 1 + (high - low) // num_buckets

    for value in array:
        # Determine in which bucket to place this value
        index_b = (value - low) // span 
        buckets[index_b].append(value)
    
    # Concatenate the buckets (each sorted) into the result list
    return [value
        for bucket in buckets
        for value in sorted(bucket)
    ]

